# Show up value of select option in IE

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a html select object and its options in IE.

My html

```
<select  id="Select1" onchange="closeMenu1(this.value)">
                                                 <option></option>
                                                 <option>1</option>
                                                 <option>2</option>
```

And the javascript

```
            function closeMenu1 (x) {
                                           var show = document.getElementById("divID");
                                           show.innerHTML = x;
                           }
```

Now, in every browser except the IEs the divID will show up the value which I selected in the select object. But IE doesn’t. Can somebody please tell me a way around that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your options actually do not have values set, so you have two options
**1) Set them**

```
<select  id="Select1" onchange="closeMenu1(this.value)">
<option value=''></option>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

**2)Use The selected index's text**

Answer (score 0):

Change your onchange event handler to as given below:

```
<select  id="Select1" onchange="closeMenu1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value from inside your closeMenu1 function instead of trying to pass it in:

```
function closeMenu1() {
    var val = document.getElementById("Select1").value;
    var show = document.getElementById("divID");
    show.innerHTML = val;
}
```

Then change the `onchange` attribute to simply `onchange="closeMenu1()"`.